# Android Studio Debugging options

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-studio

I have a really annoying bug that has crept into my android app and I can't locate the cause (although it is possibly because I upgraded to SDK 23).

I am dynamically referencing a series of ImageView elements and filling the ImageView with a bitmap:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(context.getResources().getIdentifier(result.getView(), "id", context.getString(R.string.packagename)));
img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

All of the ImageViews were filling correctly and now just one of the images is not filling (but the others are)

I suspect that the image is filling but is subsequently being either overwritten, hidden, sent to back or something else.

I have tried the debugger in Android studio that appears to confirm the ImageView is being correctly referenced and there is an image in 'bitmap' but what I can't seem to do is find if it is subsequently changed

**Question**
Is there a way to set a debugging 'trap' to catch whenever a Resource ID is accessed (i.e. I want to know when there are changes to my R.id.inv_image

Comment: before you upgrade to sdk 23 was it working?have you tried to set a different bitmap but not dynamically for example one static bitmap that you imported? you could put a Log.w() and logging the bitmap that is loading to see what happends.  EDIT : you said all bitmaps are loaded ok except one..is this in a loop? are you sure the loop is executed as many times as your bitmaps?

Comment: try breakpoints i will show you the value currently being set

Comment: i am not sure about debuging , but you can try logging; where ever you set bitmap for the image view add a log line that shows ID being accessed, and look at the output logs, if you see a line duplicated (with same ID) then that's what you need to dig into (suggestion) loga line contains these params `context.getResources().getIdentifier(result.getView(), "id", context.getString(R.string.packagename))` to wrap it up, all logs should NOT display same ID twice.

Comment: Tony: I can't be certain about sdk23 - problem occurred about the same time but not sure it was that.
I have created a new 'dummy' ImageView' at the bottom of my layout and when I call the img.setImageBitmap() above I also setImageBitmap in the dummy image view using the same bitmap - this displays properly so I'm fairly certain I have a valid bitmap.

Comment: ColdFire: the breakpoint only confirms the ID and bitmap being set which seem to be ok
Yazan: I think I will do a 'find' on each ImageView and log that + all subsequent actions... a bit laborious, I was hoping I could monitor the view itself

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestions and have now resolved problem - may be helpful to someone in the future!

I had an ImageView with and xml setting:

```
 android:layout_height="400dp"
 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/value_title"
```

So this anchored the base of the ImageView and the 400dp height was bigger than the available space on the display (?? ImageView was sticking out of the top but truncated??)

I believe that prior to sdk 23 the bitmap I put in the box was bottom aligned and I could see it without problem as the height of the bitmap was about half the ImageView height and filled the visible ImageView perfectly.

From sdk 23 it seems the bitmap is top aligned and so the image was invisible as the bitmap was placed above the viewable region, and all I could see was the blank bottom of the ImageView.

Fixed it by reducing the height of ImageView:

```
 android:layout_height="106dp"
```